# How can I build in sbt with an unreleased version of the Scala standard library?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to use the standard library of Scala 2.13.xx to use the latest unreleased version of the concurrency library.
I have tried to use it:

`scalaVersion := "2.13.0-M1"`

which leads to:

`[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.twitter#util-collection_2.13.0-M1;18.9.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.13.0-M1;0.8: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scalactic#scalactic_2.13.0-M1;3.0.5: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.13.0-M1;3.0.5: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.storm-enroute#scalameter_2.13.0-M1;0.8.2: not found`

Is there any way to use the latest unreleased version of the Scala standard library with sbt or is it not possible because of the dependencies which are not built with Scala 2.13.xx?

Comment: note that the current Scala 2.13 milestone is 2.13.0-M5. to see what libraries are available for M5, see https://github.com/scala/make-release-notes/blob/2.13.x/projects-2.13.md. it includes a link to a twitter/util ticket that shows that they haven't published for M5 yet, nor has scala-stm.

Comment: what is your goal in wanting to use a 2.13 milestone? it's hard to give specific advice on this without knowing what your actual motivation is

Comment: I want to use the latest futures and promises library, thx, I will use the latest milestone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `scalaVersion` will use both the compiler and the standard library for that version.

But any dependencies need to be built with a binary compatible Scala version. For milestones, that's only the same milestone. If you look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalactic/scalactic etc, all of them except ScalaMeter and util-collection do have versions published for 2.13.0-M2.

For the missing dependencies, you can get the sources, change *their* `scalaVersion` and use `sbt publishLocal` (or equivalent if any of them use build systems other than SBT). Hopefully they'll build and work with no source changes.

Technically you *can* also change only the standard library version by using

```
autoScalaLibrary := false
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.13.0-M1" % "test"
```

but this is unlikely to work well (if at all).